# Java Eclipse export runnable .exe file with mac Mojave upward

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, exe, launch4j

I created an application that I want my friend to be able to run from his computer (we both have macs), but I don't know how to export it. I tried using launch4j but after trying to decompress the package my Decompressor threw a corrupted file error. I also had the jar version of the file, but my computer gives me this error message when I try to open it: The jar file could not be launched. Check the console for possible error messages.

I'd also like to solve this problem for future java projects. Is it possible that I need to design some semblance of a user interface to export this project? The purpose of the project is mostly to be able to access a website remotely so I just used a Scanner object and System.out.print in the console for the user interactions. Could it be my JRE/JDK? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Can you include the error messages in your post? That might help other people to answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, the error messages aren't much more than what I said, but here are the full messages: "Decompression was unsuccessful. Data is corrupted" and "The Java class file "WebAccessor.class" (the main) could not be launched. Check the console for possible error messages."